# How to get an iframe to show when hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that I want the user to see. When the user clicks on this image I want the image to go away and have the video show in it's place. Can someone show me how to do this?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
<div id="homeflash" style="height:413px; background-image:url(../../../upload/1/img/homeFlashBG.jpg);">
    <a href="#">
         <img src="../../../upload/1/img/video.jpg" style="display:none" />
    </a>

    <div id="video" style="display:inline">
        <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="395" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/X8mLel_werQ?rel=0" width="691"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

If someone could edit my post to clean the code up that would be great. I can't figure it out.

To describe the code a little bit:
This is what the code should look like after I click on the image. When you first see the page, the two display styles will be reversed.

Any help will be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general Idea can be like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
   $(this).css("display","none");  // will hide your image
   $("body").append("<div id='video'></div>");   // will append div with id video, this div should have video code inside this.
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the video initially, so give it the style `display:none`. You also want to give your thumbnail image an `id` so you can reference it in jQuery. You can also remove the `<a>` tag from around the image (its not needed)

HTML

```
<div id="homeflash" style="height:413px; background-image:url(../../../upload/1/img/homeFlashBG.jpg);">
    <img id="thumbnail" src="../../../upload/1/img/video.jpg" />

    <div id="video" style="display:none">
        <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="395" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/X8mLel_werQ?rel=0" width="691"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thumbnail").click(function(){
        $(this).hide()
        $("#video").show()
    })
})
```

I would also try to avoid adding CSS styles inline if you can